Error while decrypting file using PGP decryption in Rails
I have a client file which is encrypted using PGP encryption. The encrypted file shared is in xlsx format. The PGP private key is also shared as a text file(Note that i added .pgp extension for the private key file).
I tried decrypting the file using the below code in the rails console:
crypto = GPGME::Crypto.new
GPGME::Key.import(File.open('private_key.pgp'))

cipthertext = GPGME::Data.new(File.open('encrypted_file.xlsx'))
data = crypto.decrypt cipthertext, {}

But the following error is coming when the last line is executed:
/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/gpgme-2.0.24/lib/gpgme/ctx.rb:489:in `decrypt_verify': No secret key (GPGME::Error::NoSecretKey)

I'm using gpgme gem version 2.0.24
Rails version: 7.0.8.1
I tried adding .gpg extension for the encrypted file, renaming it to 'encrypted_file.xlsx.gpg' and tried the same steps again, but still showing the same error.
Is there any issues with the code or any issues with the file extensions that i'm using?

I don't see example how you encrypt your data, I just have checked full process of encryption/decryption and this is how code can looks like
# loading public key for encryption
crypto = GPGME::Crypto.new
GPGME::Key.import(File.open(Rails.root.join('public_key.pgp')))
plaintext = GPGME::Data.new('input text')

# recipient should have your email, equal you used for generating keys
options = { sign: true, signers: '1@gmail.com', recipients: '2@gmail.com' }
data = crypto.encrypt plaintext, options
f = File.open(Rails.root.join('encrypted_file.gpg'), 'wb')
bytes_written = f.write(data)
f.close

# loading private key for decryption
GPGME::Key.import(File.open(Rails.root.join('private_key.pgp')))
cipthertext = GPGME::Data.new(File.open(Rails.root.join('encrypted_file.gpg')))
data = crypto.decrypt cipthertext, {}
puts data

And useful links for encryption/decryption - https://dev.to/humbertoa6/pgp-encryptdecrypt-file-with-ruby-on-rails-part-3-3log
And generating PGP keys - https://dev.to/humbertoa6/pgp-create-a-publicprivate-key-pairpart-2-4a7b

Hey, thanks for the reply. I was following the same blog that u have mentioned. In my case, the client handles the encryption and has provided me with the encrypted file and the private key. So, in this case, I only need the private key for decryption, right? Does it matter how the client is encrypting the file?

probably yes, you can try to create your own keys, check full process with your data - and if it works - then probably client encryption is failed
